# difference between using children prop directly and using React.Children.toArray method

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was playing with `React.Children` and `children` property and i found that there is no difference between using `children.filter()` and using `React.Children.toArray(children).filter` i was also able to render a specific child from the children props by using it's index directly and treat it like a normal array

so i wonder is there any difference between the two approaches? and if i can use the props directly with the arrays method why the react team implemented the `toString()` method in the first place

i tried console.log() the two of them and i see no defference between the two approaches

```
const ChildrenContainer = (props) => {
  const { children, howMany } = props;
  console.log(children, '\n', Children.toArray(children));
  return (
    <div className="card-columns">
      {Children.map(children, (thisArg) => thisArg)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the docs here: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactchildren you will notice some things.

1. `React.Children` deals with `null` and `undefined`. Calling `children.filter()` would error should children be null or undefined.
2. It deals with `<Fragment>` children
3. Includes helper functions such as `.only()` that provide more react specific capabilities than a regular array.
4. `toArray()` alters keys to preserve semantics of nested arrays.

So in your specific case, you might not notice any difference. But even if you are certain that `children` will always be a usable array, it is still good practice to use `React.children`. This is because it abstracts away the children concept so that your code is more future proofed (for changes to your code, and potential changes to react itself).

Comment: i don't get how it can `children` can have null or undefined even though it is constructed from what we pass to it.

Comment: and can you explain more what semantics means here that `toArray()` is preserving

Comment: As the docs say, each key is prefixed before returning the array. This is so that say you had nested children, their keys would stay unique (as they otherwise might not have been).